# How to copy defaults from base table into view?

Tags: postgresql, view

I have table and view:

```
CREATE TABLE base_table (id int, ts timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now());
CREATE VIEW a_view AS SELECT * FROM base_table;
```

Please advice me a query how to select all defaults from `base_table` and apply them to `a_view`

Despite on `The view will automatically show those default values for any row that was inserted` This is not true if view have `instead of insert` trigger. At this case I get error:

```
ERROR:  null value in column "ts" violates not-null constraint
```

Thus I want tables defaults to be applied before `instead of insert` trigger.

I can `alter table "a_view" alter ts set default now();` but I want do this for many columns and views via `pg` system catalog tables

**UPD**

My trigger function looks like:

```
execute format('
  create or replace function %s_insert()
  returns trigger as $fn$
  begin
  IF( new.id is null ) THEN
    if( new.app_period is null ) THEN
      INSERT INTO "%s" ( %s )
      values ( %s )
      returning id, %s, app_period INTO new;
    ELSE
      INSERT INTO "%s" ( %s, app_period )
      values ( %s, new.app_period )
      returning id, %s, app_period INTO new;
    END IF;
  ELSE
    if( new.app_period is null ) THEN
      INSERT INTO "%s" ( id, %s )
      values ( new.id, %s )
      returning id, %s, app_period INTO new;
    ELSE
      INSERT INTO "%s" ( id, %s, app_period )
      values ( new.id, %s, new.app_period )
      returning id, %s, app_period INTO new;
    END IF;
  END IF;
  return NEW;
  end;
  $fn$ language plpgsql;
```

Where `%s` is `table name` and `table's columns` correspondingly

From the start `id` and `app_period` has defaults, now default values has more fields and it becomes unmaintainable to write separate `IF` branch for each variant of defaults.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: not when `instead of insert` triggers exist

Comment: What does your insert statement look like?

Comment: @EugenKonkov: that is an import piece of information that you should have included in your question from the start.

Comment: @Jeremy: I have added this info.